# Rabbitmq: set per-message TTL during basicNack()?

Tags: rabbitmq

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html says that we can only set per-message TTL when we publish a message. 
In my use cases, when consumer receive a message from rabbitmq, for some reason it cannot distribute this message. So the consumer basicNack this message by setting re-enqueue = true. The problem is, it may introduce broadcast storm. 
So I was wondering, can I set a TTL for this message during basicNack()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The basicNack API doesn't allow that. More info here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html